# SQL: Select (null = null);

Tags: sql, postgresql-8.4

This question is out of a databases exam i was looking at, so it might be nothing one can ever use in a real situation...

> What output does the following valid SQL statement produce? Explain your answer!
>
> SELECT (NULL = NULL);

I can easily produce the output of the statement, which is

```
school=> select (null = null);
 ?column?
----------

(1 row)
```

in psql 8.4.11, but how and why this is the answer i don't know... I would have guessed it tries to evaluate the expression inside the brackets and comes up with true/false but apparently it doesn't.

Any hints on why it behaves like it does?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify my question: It looks like the result is 1 empty row. I can't / don't want to change my query statement as its given by the exam excercise. But where does it come from? Why isn't the result empty... ?

Comment: @nonnb: No. `null != null` (or to use the inequality operator specified in the SQL standard, `null <> null`) is also neither true nor false, since you can't say that two unknown values are known to be not equal. See @Oded's answer.

Comment: allow me to extends this  question... what about `select ARRAY[null]::bigint[] && ARRAY[null]::bigint[]` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NULL` stands for "Unknown Value". It is not known whether a value is true or false or anything else.

So, when comparing two unknown values, what would the answer be? Is UnknownA equal to UnknownB?

Answer? Unknown...

Here is an example for SQL Server:

```
IF (NULL = NULL)
  PRINT 'Equals'

IF (NULL != NULL)
  PRINT 'Not Equals'


IF (NULL IS NULL)
  PRINT 'IS'

IF (NULL IS NOT NULL)
  PRINT 'IS NOT'
```

The only thing that gets printed: `IS`

Comment: My understanding of the question was: Why can't I do something like `select 1 = 1` to produce `true`or `false`

Comment: +1 Also if one value is known `select (1=null)` gives NULL answer

Comment: @juergend you can, if you're not using MS SQL.

Comment: @juergend - The question is specifically about `NULL` behavior.

Comment: So it actually DOES evaluate the expression, but the result is `NULL` again makes sense

Comment: You might want to expand your answer to include `IS DISTINCT FROM` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, the expected answer is `NULL`. That's what MySQL does. That's what PostgreSQL returns as well, actually. Probably, your SQL client just doesn't show the single row where the only returned value is a `NULL`.

MS SQL server doesn't have a boolean type, though, so it cannot just select a result of boolean expression. So the result in MS SQL is an error.

The point of the question is to check your understanding of NULL logic in SQL. Instead of `=`, you should use the `IS` operator when comparing to `NULL` (unless the `ANSI_NULLS` option is set to true in MySQL).

Comment: You could use `IF (NULL = NULL)`.

Comment: @Oded This would return false.

Comment: As would `IF (NULL != NULL)`.

Comment: Ah, you probably meant, in MS SQL server. You should've specified that.

Comment: @Shedal: The question is flagged as being about PostgreSQL, not SQL Server.  The PostgreSQL behavior conforms to what is required by the standard, so it *should* generalize to some degree....